# is it possible to pass/append additional info to scenario.attach() from step definition

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

```
@When("^Sample Steps$")
public void sampleSteps() {
     String description = "Additional Description";
}
```

Hook class, here capturing the screenshots.

```
public class AssertHook extends Context {

    private Scenario scenario;

    private final WebDriver appiumDriver;

    public AssertHook() {
        appiumDriver = getDriver();

    }

    @AfterStep
    public void takeScreenShotsOnStepFailure(Scenario scenario) {
        switch (scenario.getStatus()) {
            case SKIPPED, PENDING, UNDEFINED, AMBIGUOUS, FAILED, UNUSED -> {
                try {
                    byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) appiumDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                    scenario.attach(new ImageUtilities().resizeBytesImage(screenshot), "image/png", "Description");
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    log.error(exception.getCause().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in the above case, the description pass in scenario.attach will be same for all the scenarios. Is it possible to append description given in step definitions to Hook. I don't want to use scenario.attach() inside step definitions.